# CSS 3D Transform in Highcharts code?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is possible to use CSS 3D Transform in Highcharts code ?
I added a pattern (an image) to frame ("bottom") of my 3d chart, and i want that when i rotate the chart, also the image must rotates. 
My charts is this:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/grid-light

So i must use 3d Transform....

For example:  rotateX; rotateY, perspective...
But i don't know if is possible to use CSS 3D Transform in this way...

Comment: SVG and CSS3 3D transform do not play well together. Browsers that support them mark the feature as entirely experimental and the implementations and APIs differ a lot. IE and Opera don't support it at all, Firefox and Safari offer incomplete implementations.

Comment: so i think that is impossible to do what i want to do....   Thanks Sergiu

Comment: probably the best solution would be embedding you're image direcly below the chart in SVG...

Comment: below the chart? but how can i transform the image ? the problem is the incomplete implementations by browser...   Do you know how does highcharts to transform the 3d chart when the chart is rotated ? What does it use?

Comment: It uses SVG transforms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

Comment: Only SVG Transform? Are you sure? I am not sure... Because i think that there is also 3D transform... Or perspective.. No?

Comment: if highcharts uses only svg transform, can you learn me how is possible (see the image in the link) to transform the first rect in the second rect ? http://i57.tinypic.com/11t5ph5.png